# Using selector with JMSMessageID always returns null

Tags: jms

Here I'm trying to delete a message from the queue. But the message returns always null. Even though there is a message exist for the provided jmsId.
What I'm I doing wrong here.

Note: queue initialization is proper, using the same for fetching the information from queue

```java
public void markAsViewed(String jmsId) throws JMSException, NamingException {
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/qTt");
        mQueue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/qTtQueueRef");
        jmsConnection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        jmsSession = jmsConnection.createSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        messageConsumer = jmsSession.createConsumer(mQueue, "JMSMessageID='" + jmsId + "'");
        Message inMessage = messageConsumer.receive(1000);// inMessage value is null always
    }
```

sample JmsId value is

```java
jmsId ="ID:789aba4c22aebc7c99974c06110a134f0000000000000001 ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least you aren't calling [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#start--) on your `Connection` which means messages will *never* flow to your consumer. Add this line after you invoke `createConnection()`:

```java
jmsConnection.start();
```

You may also have a problem with your `jmsId` as it contains a space at the end which seems unlikely to be valid.